# see inner exception of 500 Internal server error

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I'm getting 500 internal server error after modifying the `web.config` file. Isn't there any way to see where is the problem in web.config? (e.g. which line, ...)

Answer (score 0):

if your using IIS7,.net 3.5 check in Handlers section it may cause giving error,if the following code is not there in between system.webserver,add it

```
 <system.webServer> 
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> 
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

The validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" will allow you to keep your httpHandlers section populated without throwing an error (useful if you are debugging on a cassini / iis6 server) and the entry in the  section will configure it for your IIS7 server.

The runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is not strictly required but you will probably find yourself needing it if you are new to configuring IIS7 :)

Comment: If the problem is from `web.config` file (some misconfiguration), will it show the error??